# Java Login Form

Tags: java

Greeting to everyone.

I'm currently making Java restaurant project using MVC for portfolio. Right now, I'm stuck at login form. My problem is I forget how to logging in as a user (Admin or Customer) in MySQL.

In my login form, there are username textfield, password field, login and exit button.[image]

There's no user type because there's only one admin. I don't want to deal with multiple admin.

The name of database is restaurant. Right now, there's only one table: user. There are some data I manually inserted.

[image]

After login successful, view will change to Admin or User depending on user type.

These are ControllerLogin and Database. The database I copy paste from another project from my classmate.

```
    public class ControllerLogin extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener {
    private ViewLogin view;
    private Database db;

    public ControllerLogin() {
        view = new ViewLogin();
        db = new Database();
        view.addActionListener(this);
        view.setVisible(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if (source.equals(view.getBtnLogin())) {

            btnLoginActionPerformed();
        }

        if (source.equals(view.getBtnExit())) {

            btnExitActionPerformed();
        }
    }

    public void btnLoginActionPerformed() {

    }

    public void btnExitActionPerformed() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public class Database {

private Connection conn;
private Statement stmt;
private ResultSet rs;

public void connect() {

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/restaurant";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

---

Edit 1:

I searched video how to make login form and found one. I tried to code it on my program, but it's still wrong said that "java.lang.NullPointerException."

```
public void btnLoginActionPerformed() {

    db.connect();
    String sql = "Select * from user where username=? and password=?";
    try {

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, view.getUsername());
        pst.setString(2, view.getPassword());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password", "Access Denied", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

}
```

Comment: You mean you don't  know how to verify whether is user or admin ?

Comment: Kind of. I know the logic is that you get the texfield and password from the form. Then search them in the table to get it. After that, check whether it's admin or customer. It's just... I don't know what's the code. I once write it before, but I have forgotten it.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using below code

```
public void btnLoginActionPerformed() {

    db.connect();
    String sql = "Select * from user where username=? and password=?";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, view.getUsername());
        pst.setString(2, view.getPassword());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            if(view.getUsername.equals("Admin"))
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome admin");
            }else
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome user");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password", "Access Denied", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```